# Paginação sem php e mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer uma paginação simples, apenas clicar no botão "2" por exemplo e ela acontecer. Tentei usar esse, mas não consegui:

https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Desde indicar um tutorial no Youtube, artigo, livro, ajuda pessoal, qualquer coisa.

Eu queria fazer sem usar php ou mysql e coisas do tipo, só com html, css e js.

Aqui está meu código, queria que ao clicar no 1, 2, 3 etc, só trocassem as informações da `div` acima, não queria ter que criar uma página "clone" e mudar apenas as informações.

Meu código:

https://pastebin.com/N7dPxR0H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar esse plugin citado "twbs-pagination" da seguinte forma:

Baixe o zip na página do plugin e carregue-o no seu projeto usando o arquivo `jquery.twbsPagination.min.js`:

```
<script src="jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
```

Adicionei as classes `hide` (nativa do Bootstrap, que oculta a `div`) e `paginas` (criada por mim para dar uma referência às `divs` que serão manipuladas, como se cada `div` com esta classe fosse uma *página*):

```
<div class="row hide paginas">
   <div class="col-md-2 data-evento">
      <div>

         <h1> DOMINGO  </h1>
         <h2> 12 NOV</h2>
         <h3> 22:00 </h3>

      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="col-md-10 desc-evento">

      <h1> Foo Fighters + Queens of the Stone Age</h1>
      <h3> São Paulo - SP</h3>
      <h4> Allianz Parque</h4>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S </button>

   </div>
</div>
```

Em seguida, na última `div`, onde estarão os botões, adicionei a classe `paginas-bts`, para diferenciá-la das outras:

```
<div class="row paginas-bts">
   <div class="col-md-5">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-5">
      <ul id="pagination">
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Para finalizar, basta chamar o plugin no jQuery após o carregamento da página (veja que criei algumas variáveis para contar o número de `divs` automaticamente):

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    var pag_div = $("#conteudo .container div.paginas"); // seleciono as divs que serão paginadas, exceto a que contém os botões
    var num_div = pag_div.length; // conto o número de divs
   $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
     totalPages: num_div,
     visiblePages: 5,
     onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        pag_div.addClass("hide"); // escondo todas as divs
        pag_div.eq(page-1).removeClass("hide"); // mostro a div da página
     }
   });
});
```

**Veja em ação:**

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
    var pag_div = $("#conteudo .container div.paginas");
    var num_div = pag_div.length;
   $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
     totalPages: num_div,
     visiblePages: 5,
     onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        pag_div.addClass("hide");
        pag_div.eq(page-1).removeClass("hide");
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/js/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="conteudo">
   <div class="container">

      <div class="row hide paginas">
         <div class="col-md-2 data-evento">
            <div>

               <h1> DOMINGO  </h1>
               <h2> 12 NOV</h2>
               <h3> 22:00 </h3>

            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10 desc-evento">

            <h1> Foo Fighters + Queens of the Stone Age</h1>
            <h3> São Paulo - SP</h3>
            <h4> Allianz Parque</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S </button>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row hide paginas">
         <div class="col-md-2 data-evento">
            <div>

               <h1> DOMINGO  </h1>
               <h2> 13 NOV</h2>
               <h3> 22:00 </h3>

            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10 desc-evento">

            <h1> Foo Fighters + Queens of the Stone Age</h1>
            <h3> São Paulo - SP</h3>
            <h4> Allianz Parque</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S </button>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row hide paginas">
         <div class="col-md-2 data-evento">
            <div>

               <h1> DOMINGO  </h1>
               <h2> 14 NOV</h2>
               <h3> 22:00 </h3>

            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10 desc-evento">

            <h1> Foo Fighters + Queens of the Stone Age</h1>
            <h3> São Paulo - SP</h3>
            <h4> Allianz Parque</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S </button>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row hide paginas">
         <div class="col-md-2 data-evento">
            <div>

               <h1> DOMINGO  </h1>
               <h2> 15 NOV</h2>
               <h3> 22:00 </h3>

            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10 desc-evento">

            <h1> Foo Fighters + Queens of the Stone Age</h1>
            <h3> São Paulo - SP</h3>
            <h4> Allianz Parque</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S </button>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row hide paginas">
         <div class="col-md-2 data-evento">
            <div>

               <h1> DOMINGO  </h1>
               <h2> 16 NOV</h2>
               <h3> 22:00 </h3>

            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-10 desc-evento">

            <h1> Foo Fighters + Queens of the Stone Age</h1>
            <h3> São Paulo - SP</h3>
            <h4> Allianz Parque</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">I N F O R M A Ç Õ E S </button>

         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row paginas-bts">
         <div class="col-md-5">
         </div>
   
         <div class="col-md-5">
            <ul id="pagination">
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<section>
```

Comment: Meu código está assim: https://pastebin.com/kUE99Gh9, mas está tudo branco, a  única coisa eu aparece são os números da pagination. O que eu fiz de errado? E já agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: @Kali Fiz uma alteração no jQuery da resposta, substitua para testar. Agora, olhando o seu código, o correto é chamar primeiro a biblioteca jQuery e depois as demais.

Comment: @ÐvÐ estou observando seu exemplo, e queria perguntar... Eu conseguiria paginar resultados dentro de uma janela modal com este código

Comment: @Kali Observe no meu código que na UL `pagination` você não precisa colocar os links com os botões, o plugin já coloca. Tem que deixar essa UL vazia.

Comment: Ótimo!!! Agora está funcionando, agradeço imensamente! Só mais uma pergunta, tem como eu mostrar mais de uma DIV? No momento aparece apenas uma, tem como aumentar esse numero para 5 ou 6 por exemplo?

Comment: @Kali Cada div com a class "hide paginas" é como se fosse uma página. Se você quiser mostrar mais itens por página, basta colocar as mais divs dentro.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Deixa eu perguntar, sei que faz um tempo que você respondeu...mas sabe na pagination, os nomes? Tem como mudar o next, last, previous etc pra "próximo, anterior? Tem como modificar o nome dessas coisas? Não sei como fazer isso mexendo no js, apenas consegui modificar coisas via css, tipo cor